# CSS Positionsing to main Footer at the end of the webiste

Tags: css, web, bootstrap-5, footer

type here

Guys currently i am building a blog website for practicing basic ejs so i am  facing a problem that if i start adding my blog contents to my website . While adding the content i am not facing any problem but once i reach the end of the page . My content goes back of the footer div
Rather than blog content to placed above the footer..
This is the problem i am facing right now . I guess the problem is in my CSS part.
Help me to fix this thing.

This is the only part where is used positioning in my entire code

[Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uNFW.png)

I tried to change postion of the footer . and also but adding html tag postion to relative still it didn`t work out

```
CSS:
.footer {
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}
```

Comment: try `position: sticky` or `fixed`

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**